# How to know if an email date was modified from the server?

Tags: email

This is the escenario:

Some person A "maybe" modified the email server date, to another year, let's say 2015. Then, he sent an email to person B, and B is worried that the date of the email was changed from the origin, because A says that tha email was sent really in 2015 but B is pretty sure that he didn't read it before.

Where and how should B to inspect to verify that the email date was actually modified? maybe son logs? or what

Comment: I'd think the full email headers would show enough info. Those get added to as it goes from server to server... Out of the sender's hands.

Comment: If the mailbox is on the same server you might need to look in a log.  On the other hand, If the email left the originating server then just view full headers of the received email itself, as mentioned above timestamps are added at each server and are out of control of the sender. That may also be the case if sending and receiving mail servers are the same.